# Is there an Objective C equivalent of the JavaScript method encode()?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, xml

```
NSString *searchString = @"Lyngbø";
NSLog("%@",[searchString stringByAddingPercentEscapeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

**This gives me : Lyng%C3%B8**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(escape("Lyngbø"));
</script>
```

**This gives me : Lyngb%F8**

The web search engine i am developing against doesnt understand the Objectiv C's way of encoding the string, and returns nothing when searching for words that contains either æ. ø or å

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Charset difference. Instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`, use `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`.